# why $(\operatorname{GL}_n(F), +)$ is not a group?

Tags: group-theory

why $(\operatorname{GL}_n(F), +)$ is not a group? And I think the identity is zero matrix.

Comment: Do you know what $GL_n(F)$ means?

Comment: If $A\in GL_n(F)$ then also $B:=-A$ in $GL_n(F)$, but $A+B=0\notin GL_n(F)$.

Answer (score 5):

Think $n=1$ and $F = \mathbf{R}$, say. So $\operatorname{GL}_{1}(\mathbf{R})$ consists of all $1 \times 1$ matrices $[a]$, with $a \in \mathbf{R}$, $a \ne 0$.   Now $[a]+[b] = [a+b]$. Is the sum of two nonzero real numbers always nonzero?

**PS** So $+$ is not even an operation on $\operatorname{GL}_{1}(\mathbf{R})$.

Answer (score 4):

$\operatorname{GL}_n(F)$ means all $n\times n$ matrices of non-zero determinant over the field $F$.  The zero matrix has determinant $0$, so is never an element of $GL_n(F)$.

This proves that $\operatorname{GL}_n(F)$ is never a group under addition, since the only possible identity element is the zero matrix (if $A+B = A$, then $B = 0$).  However, much more important is the point mentioned by Andreas in his answer:  addition is not even an operation on $\operatorname{GL}_n(F)$, since for example the identity matrix $I_n$ is always in $\operatorname{GL}_n(F)$, and so is $-I_n$, but $I_n + -I_n = 0\notin \operatorname{GL}_n(F)$.